# a scalar multiple of the zero matrix is the zero scalar

Tags: linear-algebra

is it true or false? to my understanding, it should be false as a zero matrix can have any scalar. Am I interpreting this question wrong?

Comment: Your understanding seems correct. Is there a reason why you're doubting yourself?

Comment: I guess i just got confused by the grammar of the question. Appreciate your resonse

Comment: A scalar multiple of a matrix (that is, the product of a scalar and a matrix) is a matrix, not a number.

Comment: But I don't know what you mean by, "a zero matrix can have any scalar". What does it mean for a matrix to "have" a scalar?

Comment: Suppose a zero matrix A exists. what I meant was cA is also a zero matrix regardless of c being zero

Comment: oh but i understand your point as well, i was reading the question wrong

Comment: You don't have to *suppose* a zero matrix exists – it certainly does exist. And, yes, if you multiply it by any scalar, you get the zero matrix. Do you understand why?

Comment: Yes, I do. A scalar multiplied with a matrix results in a matrix

Comment: Yes, but do you understand why you get the zero matrix?